# ListLogLinearPlot with Legends

Tags: legending, plotting, logarithmic-scale

I need to plot this data in Log scale for both axes, and also need to add a legend. But since they are joined dots, the legend that appears is just a dot instead the plotstyle I choose.

```
data1 = {{0.0001`, 618.69`}, {0.00010202`, 630.68`}, {0.00010408`, 
    642.89`}, {0.00010618`, 655.35`}, {0.00010833`, 
    668.04`}, {0.00011052`, 680.98`}, {0.00011275`, 
    694.17`}, {0.00011503`, 707.61`}, {0.00011735`, 
    721.32`}, {0.00011972`, 735.29`}, {0.00012214`, 
    749.53`}, {0.00012461`, 764.04`}, {0.00012712`, 
    778.84`}, {0.00012969`, 793.92`}, {0.00013231`, 
    809.29`}, {0.00013499`, 824.96`}, {0.00013771`, 
    840.93`}, {0.00014049`, 857.21`}, {0.00014333`, 
    873.81`}, {0.00014623`, 890.72`}, {0.00014918`, 
    907.96`}, {0.0001522`, 925.54`}, {0.00015527`, 
    943.45`}, {0.00015841`, 961.71`}, {0.00016161`, 
    980.32`}, {0.00016487`, 999.29`}, {0.0001682`, 
    1018.6`}, {0.0001716`, 1038.3`}, {0.00017507`, 
    1058.4`}, {0.0001786`, 1078.9`}, {0.00018221`, 
    1099.8`}, {0.00018589`, 1121.`}, {0.00018965`, 
    1142.7`}, {0.00019348`, 1164.8`}, {0.00019739`, 
    1187.3`}, {0.00020138`, 1210.3`}, {0.00020544`, 
    1233.7`}, {0.00020959`, 1257.5`}, {0.00021383`, 
    1281.8`}, {0.00021815`, 1306.6`}, {0.00022255`, 
    1331.8`}, {0.00022705`, 1357.6`}, {0.00023164`, 
    1383.8`}, {0.00023632`, 1410.5`}, {0.00024109`, 
    1437.8`}, {0.00024596`, 1465.5`}, {0.00025093`, 
    1493.8`}, {0.000256`, 1522.6`}, {0.00026117`, 
    1552.`}, {0.00026645`, 1582.`}, {0.00027183`, 
    1612.5`}, {0.00027732`, 1643.6`}}
ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dotted, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data"}]
```

Comment: `ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dotted, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"data"}]]`?

Comment: ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dotted, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Automatic}, {"data"}]]

Comment: @kguler , it works perfectly.

Comment: @Jhon, I get a square instead a line as a legend. Since I pretend to plot several sets of data, a square could not be useful. Thanks

Comment: @Resanrom, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dotted, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"data"}]]
```